# Регистрация servlet в jetty 9: StackOverFlow при отсутствии DefaultServlet

Tags: java, servlet, jetty

Я запускаю Jetty сервер и пытаюсь зарегистрировать сервлет. Вот в таком виде все работает:

```
import com.crest.test.http.XmlParserServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;

public class JettyServer {
    public static void start(int port) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(port);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setResourceBase("src/main/resources/pages");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Add dump servlet
        context.addServlet(XmlParserServlet.class, "/xml");
        // Add default servlet
        context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Но стоит мне удалить строчку с DefaultServlet - получаю Error 500: StackOverFlow. Вот сам сервлет:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XmlParserServlet extends DefaultServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("xml.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Если что стакТрэйс тоже скину, просто он там километровый. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

[DefaultServlet](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.17.v20150415/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html) отвечает за загрузку статического контента, поэтому он мапится на `/`. То есть все запросы, на которые нету мапинга приходят на него, в том числе и запросы с `*.jsp`.

---

> request.getRequestDispatcher("xml.jsp").forward(request, response);

Вы используете запрос JSP который должен обрабатываться этим сервлетом, иначе диспатчер выдаст ошибку, что файл не найден или что-то в этом роде, и затем выкинет ошибку 500.