# HTML img не отображается картинка по абсолютному пути

Tags: java, html, spring, img, thymeleaf

Есть у меня программа, с помощью которой пользователь выбирает себе аватар.
Пока он не выбрал аватар - отображается стандартная - та, которую выбрала я

**properties**:

```
image.url=https://media.kasperskydaily.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/90/2017/05/06040328/incognito-mode-featured.jpg
```

**controller**:

```java
@Value("${image.url}")
private String imageUrl;

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model, Principal principal) {

    User currentUser = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    List<Secret> userSecrets = userService.getUsersSecrets(principal.getName());

    Image image = imageRepository.findByUserUsername(principal.getName());
    imageUrl = image == null ? imageUrl : image.getName();
    log.info("Image name: {}", image.getName());

    model.addAttribute("image", imageUrl);
    model.addAttribute("user", currentUser);
    model.addAttribute("secretsSize", userSecrets.size());

    return "home";
}
```

Должна сразу сказать - сохраняется картинка хорошо (на жестком диске, а в бд только метаданные).
В логах вывелось название картинки, в проводнике я скопипастила и вставила в поиск - картинка открылась.
Выглядит это примерно так: `E:\uploaded\image.png`.
Но по ссылке из интернета картинка открывается хорошо, а с комплюктера не хочет

HTML:

```
<img th:src="${image}" style="width: 30%" class="card-img-top" alt="Your avatar">
//из кода выше на страницу передается переменная с расположением картинки и вставляется как ресурс
```

Немного поэкспериментировав без шаблонизаторов, с чистым html - трабл точно такой же: из инета - пожалуйста, а с комплюктера никак. Как можно решить эту проблему?

(Запускаю на localhost с другого диска, на C:\Users...)

Comment: Как выглядит url картинки, которые хранятся в БД?

Comment: Если вот так вот `E:\uploaded\image.png` то это долгая история(ответ вам). Если никто в течении пару часов не ответит, то напишу ночью ответ.

Comment: Даа, так и выглядит. Короче - проект, который я делаю, находится в папке C:/users/мася/desktop/... Из-за того, что в урле русские буквы, при попытке сохранить файлик эти буквы превращаются в иероглифы, и программа не видит путь. Тоесть, забираю файлик на сервер со странички с помощью ```MultipartFile```, вот она и требует все на английском (а путь ему нужен абсолютный). Решила и сохранить на другой диск (E:/), без юзеров - все сохранилось, путь он видит. Но, похоже, невозможно загрузить фото на страницу не из корня сайта?

Comment: у меня сейчас нет особо времени. Если хотите - можете мне в телеграм позвонить(он у меня в профиле указан) я вам голосом за пару минут объясню. Полноценный ответ писать час если не два и на это время у меня только ночью будет - можете подождать. Поэтому смотрите.

Comment: Видимо нужно ссылку кодировать декодировать URLEncode/URLEncode (https://www.urlencoder.org/)

Comment: @NMD, нужно не ссылку кодировать, а файлы(изображения) веб-сервером раздавать, сейчас она не раздаёт их.

Comment: Не все так просто как кажется. Вы думали что можно подгружать файлы откуда угодно на сервере? Советую почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881595/204920)

Comment: @Anastasiya, извиняюсь. Я ночью осилил половину ответа, но на вторую меня не хватило. Постараюсь днем найти время и дописать. Кстати предлодложение относительно ТГ актуально если вам нужно срочно узнать.

Comment: @МихаилРебров "Если никто в течении пару часов не ответит". Правильно — "В течениЕ парЫ часов".

Answer (score 1):

локально статичесая страничка работает

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <img src="https://media.kasperskydaily.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/90/2017/05/06040328/incognito-mode-featured.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

но судя по всему Ваш "чистый html" выглядит немного иначе. Если да, прикрепите и его тоже к вопросу.

Вероятно Вы используете не оригинальную ссылку на картинку, а ее локальную копию, что в принципе неплохо, т.к. на облаке в определенный момент картинка может быть удалена.

Далее, есть несколько потенциальных ошибок:

1: не хватает тэга '@', см https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

```
 <img th:src="@{${image}}" style="width: 30%" class="card-img-top" alt="Your avatar">
```

2: перезаписывание переменной класса imageUrl, если контроллер синглтон (по умолчанию)

исправляется использованием локальной переменной:

```
// ...

Image image = imageRepository.findByUserUsername(principal.getName());
String userImageUrl = image == null ? imageUrl : image.getName();
log.info("Image name: {}", image.getName());

model.addAttribute("image", userImageUrl);

// ...
```